# Laptop doesn't boot

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, overheating

I have couple years old Packard bell easynote ts11-hr-777nc. Recently I had serious overheating problems so I opened the laptop and removed the dust (there wasn't alot).

Now when I press the power button, fans and lights go up, but after a second laptop shuts down. So no bios, nor windows. Did I do some damage to motherboard when I removed the dust? Is there a way to check what's wrong with my laptop?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way *for us* to determine if you damage to motherboard when you removed the dust. The only things **we** can do is to advice you to check the laptop again. Are all cables connected? Did you accidentally unplug one? Did you remove the heat sinks during cleaning; if you did, did you properly reattach them with fresh thermal paste?  etc etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Not Booting to Windows but you were getting light/s and fan on..

.You can try the Motherboard self-test first. Remove all the RAMs, if you hear a beep sound, it means that the motherboard is still functional. If there's no sound, that means that the motherboard is defective. You need to bench it and replace it, or just replace the whole unit, it will be cheaper than exchanging the board.

Comment: ..ow, that was not good.. anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: Now this is interesting. I reseted cmos and now it booted on second try.. I guess I'm not taking a risk and I'm keeping my laptop powered on forever :)

Comment: .ow, really? good for you.. but the laptop needs to be shut down once in a while.. least you can still use it.